# Select all rows where specific column value is maximum of that column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select all columns(col1, col2, col3) where value of col3 is the maximum amongst all the values in col3.

For ex, for below table

```
col1 col2 col3
abc  def  2
ghi  jkl  3
mno  pqr  2
stu  vwx  3
yza  bcd  1
```

I want the output as

```
ghi  jkl  3
stu  vwx  3
```

How can I achieve this using SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. One way is to use a sub-query to find the maximum value of `col3` and then use it in getting the desired result.

```sql
SELECT * 
   FROM TABLE
WHERE col3 = (SELECT MAX(col3) FROM TABLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table 
WHERE col3 = (SELECT MAX(col3) FROM your_table)
```